# Android: How to copy values from one column to a new column in Android table layout before updating the table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am very new to Android app development.
I want to maintain a copy of a col to a new col before updating the table.
What I'm currently doing is before updating the table in the table layout is removeAllViews().
But before removing I want to save the copy of the last updated values of a particular column.
So i want to add another column (say: lastUpdatedFSIDs) which should contain the data of FSID column of previous update.

My current implementation is like below:

public void init(long [] array)
{

```
    TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);
    stk.removeAllViews();
    String[] s=new  String[array.length];
    for(int k=0;k<array.length;k++)
    {
        s[k]= Long.toHexString(array[k]);
        Log.i(TAG,"Strings in array:"+ s[k]);
    }

    TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
    tv0.setText(" Sl.No ");
    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv0.setTextSize(20);
    tv0.setWidth(100);
    tbrow0.addView(tv0);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(" FSID ");
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv1.setTextSize(20);
    tv1.setWidth(100);
    tbrow0.addView(tv1);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText(" Status ");
    tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv2.setTextSize(20);
    tv2.setWidth(100);
    tbrow0.addView(tv2);
    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv3.setText(" Functionality ");
    tv3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv3.setTextSize(20);
    tv3.setWidth(200);
    tbrow0.addView(tv3);
    stk.addView(tbrow0);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
        t1v.setText("" + i);
        t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t1v.setTextSize(15);
        tbrow.addView(t1v);
        stk.addView(tbrow);
        TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
        t2v.setText(s[i]);
        t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t2v.setTextSize(15);
        tbrow.addView(t2v);
```

//... } }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using an `ArrayList` for storing `the data of FSID column`?

Comment: @Darkman yeah, will try that. I thought there might be some way to store in the table without creating another array.

Comment: It all depends on your implementations. Let say your array size is 30, each tens for a column, last 10 is your last data. Rather than delete all of them, you can just filling the first 20 with new data. It would be easier if you use variables like `lastDataColumn=2` for the last data column, `dataAColumn=0` for the first 10 data and `dataBColumn=1` for middle one. Then set these variables accordingly.

Comment: @Darkman but how to retain the old values inside the init() call for new updates?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that clear on what you're trying to say. Often, don't over complicated things too much. If using `ArrayList`s would makes your code cleaner and understandable,  then go for it.